# Create array from string in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex

I have the following string:

```
"Failed verification. \n Selected: First Name; Andrew; Last Name; Drew; correct options: First Name; Matt; Last Name; Darr;
```

I want to create array with data from this string that will look like this:

```
[ ["Andrew", "Matt"], ["Drew", "Darr"] ]
```

first key in array is selected option and the second one is correct option. Is there any way to do it with regex?

EDIT:
I was thinking about this a little bit and my string will look like this:

```
"Failed verification. \n Selected: First Name; Andrew; Last Name; Drew; School; selected school; correct options: First Name; Matt; Last Name; Darr; School; Correct school"
```

And the result I want to have is:

```
[ ["Andrew", "Matt"], ["Drew", "Darr"], ["selected school", "Correct school"] ]
```

Comment: If this string you get has any regular structure, I'd rather try to `#split` it i.e. on i`';'` and take parts that interest me, trimming whitespaces when necessary.

Comment: What is the rule behind it? Are you asking people to figure that out for you? I hope not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
a = "Failed verification. \n Selected: First Name; Andrew; Last Name; Drew; correct options: First Name; Matt; Last Name; Darr;"
first_names = a.scan(/(?<=First Name; )\w+/)
last_names = a.scan(/(?<=Last Name; )\w+/)
[first_names, last_names]
```

The irb output:

```
a = "Failed verification. \n Selected: First Name; Andrew; Last Name; Drew; correct options: First Name; Matt; Last Name; Darr;"
# => "Failed verification. \n Selected: First Name; Andrew; Last Name; Drew; correct options: First Name; Matt; Last Name; Darr;"
first_names = a.scan(/(?<=First Name; )\w+/)
# => ["Andrew", "Matt"]
last_names = a.scan(/(?<=Last Name; )\w+/)
# => ["Drew", "Darr"]
[first_names, last_names]
# => [["Andrew", "Matt"], ["Drew", "Darr"]]
```

For case when you have complex name use the following regexps:

```
last_names = a.scan(/(?<=Last Name; ).*?(?=;)/)
first_names = a.scan(/(?<=First Name; ).*?(?=;)/)
```

Also the irb output is the following:

```
a = "Failed verification. \n Selected: First Name; Andrew; Last Name; Drew; correct options: First Name; Matt Matt; Last Name; Darr Dar;"
# => "Failed verification. \n Selected: First Name; Andrew; Last Name; Drew; correct options: First Name; Matt Matt; Last Name; Darr Dar;"
last_names = a.scan(/(?<=Last Name; ).*?(?=;)/)
# => ["Drew", "Darr Dar"]
first_names = a.scan(/(?<=First Name; ).*?(?=;)/)
# => ["Andrew", "Matt Matt"]
[first_names, last_names]
# => [["Andrew", "Matt Matt"], ["Drew", "Darr Dar"]]
```

Comment: But this will not work when for example First name will have more than one word. It will return only first one. How can I fix this?

Comment: @MateuszUrbański Added regexps to my answer

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question becase my message will also have information about school. Could You look at this? because I can't make it work with Your code... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add one more expression. Just replace 'First Name' with 'School'

Comment: @MateuszUrbański Also you can add as many new information as you need.
You can even use iterator for this.
By the way you can even split your string by /(Selected\: |correct options\: )/ and then by semicolon and space and just select the proper elements (even ones)

Comment: Yeah I know. I did that:
first_names = a.scan(/(?<=First Name; ).*?(?=;)/)
last_names = a.scan(/(?<=Last Name; ).*?(?=;)/)
schools = a.scan(/(?<=School; ).*?(?=;)/)
[first_names, last_names, schools]

but it returns:
[["Andrew", "Matt"], ["Drew", "Darr"], ["selected school"]]

Comment: @MateuszUrbański of course, because you have no selected school in your string

Comment: Nope, I have:
"Failed verification. \n Selected: First Name; Andrew; Last Name; Drew; School; selected school; correct options: First Name; Matt; Last Name; Darr; School; Correct school"

Comment: So you didn't update it in the question. Also there is no first school value. So your string have no correct structure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89826/discussion-between-nickolay-kondratenko-and-mateusz-urbanski).

Answer (score 4):

An other way, assuming the first name and the last name are consecutive:

```
res=[[],[]]
a.scan(/First Name; ([^;]*); Last Name; ([^;]*);/) do |fn, ln|
    res[0] << fn
    res[1] << ln
end
```

Comment: btw [^;]* expression you use is better for cases we have no semicolon at the end